Django DRF deosn't deserialize json
I faced a very weird issue with django drf. The below view does not deserializes the event_time in post() method.
class EventListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        school_id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
        class_number = serializers.CharField(source='class.universal_number', read_only=True)
        class_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

        class Meta:
            model = Event
            fields = ('pk', 'event', 'school_id', 'class_number', 'class_id', 'event_time',)

  
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    filterset_class = EventFilterSet
    ordering_fields = ['event_time']


    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            Event.objects.select_related('class')
            .annotate(school_id=F('class__school'))
            .order_by('-pk')
        )


It works only after I explicitly mention event_time in the serializer:
class EventListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        school_id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
        class_number = serializers.CharField(source='class.universal_number', read_only=True)
        class_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
        event_time = serializers.DateTimeField()

        class Meta:
            model = Event
            fields = ('pk', 'event', 'school_id', 'class_number', 'class_id', 'event_time',)

  
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    filterset_class = EventFilterSet
    ordering_fields = ['event_time']


    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            Event.objects.select_related('event_class')
            .annotate(school_id=F('class__school'))
            .order_by('-pk')
        )

The model :
class Event(models.Model):
    event_class = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    event = models.CharField(choices=EventNameEnum.choices, max_length=50, db_index=True)
    event_time = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Event id: {self.pk} , Device id: {self.event_class.pk}'



Which doesn't make sense to be correct approach.
Any suggestion on how to solve the issue will be appreciated.

Try changing model = Class line in Serializer's Meta to model = Event.

@MatijaSirk, Sorry it's Event in the original code, I missed it in question.

Can you also provide model code?

@MatijaSirk yes. question edited.

I found the cause of the issue.
It stemmed from editable=False in the event_time declaration in the model:
event_time = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

When the field is declared as none editable, it should be explicitly declared in the serializer to be included in deserialization.
